# Property 'alt' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<VideoHTMLAttributes<HTMLVideoElement>, HTMLVideoElement>'. TS2322

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm making a video play in the background. I now get this error:

> Property 'alt' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<VideoHTMLAttributes, HTMLVideoElement>'.  TS2322

```
 <video
              alt={"Hero Image"}
              fit={"first-fit"}
              align={"center"}
              w={"300px"}
              h={"100%"}
              src={"/assets/herovideo.mp4"}
              loop
              autoPlay
            />
```

Comment: You can only use `alt` for images. Ain't no nothing on videos.